# How to make openid call from saml request

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, saml, keycloak

Implementing SSO in my application and from app-1 i need to make a rest call to app-2. Login in app-1 with SAML and authenticated successfully and trying for rest call from app-1 with openid but since authentication is using saml only so not able to get the access/bearer token. Please help how to get the access/bearer token from saml request/response. I'm using Keycloak Server for SSO implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

REST API need a JWT token not a SAML one.

Change SAML to OpenID Connect and it will work.

Comment: Is there any way we can get JWT token from SAML.

Comment: When you have an STS (like the one in ForgeRock AM) it could exchange a SAML assertion for an OIDC IdToken or similar

Comment: Very few STS have this capability. I am not aware of any that implement the above profile at this point.

Comment: Yes, you could build a JWT from the SAML token. The problem is signing it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

(2) Presently there is no IETF draft document regarding SAML 2.0 Profile for OpenID Connect client.

We can refer to the IETF draft document [SAML 2.0 Profile for OAuth 2.0 client](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-18).

The OAuth 2.0 Access Token using SAML Assertion filter enables an OAuth client to request an access token using a SAML assertion. This supports the OAuth 2.0 SAML flow, which is used when a client wishes to utilize an existing trust relationship, expressed through the semantics of the SAML assertion, without a direct user approval step at the authorization server. For more details on supported OAuth flows, see [API Gateway OAuth 2.0 authentication flows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55956_01/doc.11123/oauth_guide/content/oauth_flows.html).

(3) Both Auth0 and open-source WSO2 Identity Server implement the SAML profile for OpenID Connect/OAuth to convert SAML token to OpenID Connect/OAuth token, as demonstrated by [Auth0 SAML Configuration](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-configuration#saml-service-providers) and [WSO2 Adding and Configuring an Identity Provider](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adding+and+Configuring+an+Identity+Provider#AddingandConfiguringanIdentityProvider). In other words, Auth0 and WSO2 Identity Server can relay SAML authentication provided by SAML IdP to either OpenID Connect client or OAuth 2.0 client.

Comment: Agreed but doesn't answer the question. I am not aware of any IDP that implement the above profile at this point.

Comment: Auth0 is an IdP that implements the SAML profile for OpenID Connect/OAuth to convert SAML token to OpenID Connect/OAuth token, as demonstrated by  Auth0 SAML Configuration (https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-configuration#saml-service-providers). In other words, it can relay authentication provided by SAML IdP to either OpenID Connect client or OAuth 2.0 client (I have updated my answer.)